# Rails deployment on heroku crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

This is my first go around at rails deployment and i cannot figure out this issue for the life of me.  For some reason I'm not able to get my app to run.  Here's what i get when running heroku logs:

```
2012-10-12T01:44:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 54445`
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- thin (LoadError)
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:269:in `server'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-10-12T01:44:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-10-12T01:44:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-10-12T01:44:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "real" error is this:

```
`require': no such file to load -- thin (LoadError)
```

you can add the following line to your gemfile, to get it working:

```
 gem 'thin'
```

Comment: I actually had the gem in there and it wasn't working.  I believe the issue was something with the `group` block but I'm not exactly sure.  Anyways, i took it out of `group`, placed it by itself and it worked.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add 2 gem as below:

```
gem "heroku"
gem "thin"
```

And then run command line: bundle install

For more detail please check: [http://wowcode.herokuapp.com](http://wowcode.herokuapp.com/)